# prove that none of the following theories is finitely axiomatizable:

Tags: group-theory, logic, model-theory

prove that none of the following theories is finitely axiomatizable:

$(a)$ infinite models of sets with only equality;
$(b)$ fields of characteristic zero;
$(c)$ divisible Abelian groups;
$(d)$ torsion-free Abelian groups
Using the following therom:

Let K be an arbitrary class of models. Then:
$(1)$ K is an elementary class if and only if K is closed under ultraproducts and elementary equivalence.
$(2)$ K is a finitely axiomatizable class if and only if both K and the complement of K are closed under ultraproducts and elementary equivalence.

I managed to proof that $(b)$ is not finitely axiomatizable by proof by negation I assumed that if there was such finite set of sentences I can lead to a contradiction (essentially saying that theory consist of the sentences 2$\neq$0,3$\neq$0,.....,p$\neq$0 is consistit for all primes p then by compactness I get an infinite axiomatizable theory), but it doesn't use that theorm (I couldn't make the connection...).

and for (d) I claimed: lets conclude the sentensces $\varphi_n$ that say the only element raised to the $n$th power that equals $e$ is $e$.If I take the ultraproudct of groups that have torsion elements I will get an torison free group hence K is not close uneder ultraproducts hence by the theorm is not not finitly axiomtazed (but I think its a bit off ;\ my knowledge in group theory is lacking).

For the others I tried to either proof they are not closed under elementary equivalence or under ultraproducts but I didn't find a way.
Any help would be appericated !

Comment: Can you maybe find an ultraproduct of fields of characteristic $p$ that has characteristic $0$, or an ultraproduct of finite sets which is infinite ?

Comment: Unless they can all be done in one fell swoop, this is four questions.

Comment: An ultraproduct of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ over all primes $p$ with a free ultrafilter on the primes is an infinite field of characteristic zero, and a torsion-free divisible Abelian group w.r.t. addition, so it solves all four at once.

Comment: @JohnDoe mind giving a sketch of a full proof?

Comment: @Giladbe10:  Depending on which part puzzles you, this can be very long.  Can you be more specific what you don't understand?  None of the factors in the ultraproduct have any of the four properties, but the ultraproduct has all four of them.

Comment: @JohnDoe I kinda don't undesrtand how it works for (a) and (c) so if u could do a simple sketch even by dots it would be appercited !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each prime $p$, $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ has the following properties.

- It is a finite field of characteristic $p$ with $p$ elements.
- In the additive group, all non-zero elements have order $p$ so are torsion.
- It is not divisible by $p$, because $p=0$.

Now consider the ultraproduct $\text{UP}$.  The filter used is free and contains all cofinite subsets of primes.

The axioms of a field are a finite collection of statements of first-order logic, and since each factor in the ultraproduct satisfies them, the ultraproduct satisfies them and is a field.

Any positive integer $n>0$ is embedded in $\text{UP}$ as the constant sequence $(n, n, n, \dots)$.  Since $n$ is divisible by only finitely many primes, it is invertible in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ for all but finitely many primes.  Since the ultrafilter contains the complement of the set of primes dividing $n$, $n$ is invertible in $\text{UP}$ on a large set.  This implies it is invertible as an element of the field $\text{UP}$.  (In the primes dividing $n$ you put anything you want for an inverse, because that's a negligible set.)

This implies all positive integers are invertible in the field $\text{UP}$.  So it contains a copy of $\Bbb{N}, \Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$.  Its prime sub-field is $\Bbb{Q}$, so it has characteristic zero.  It is infinite.  Since it's a field extending $\Bbb{Q}$, it is a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$.  The additive group of any vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$ is a torsion-free divisible Abelian group, so the additive group of $\text{UP}$ is torsion-free and divisible.

Comment: I really appreicate it ! Thanks! @JohnDoe